# My discord bot wont respond to any message that I send

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

trying to do an on_message so i can make a discord bot but it just doesnt work. the bot will say that it is logged in but no message sent will make the bot respond. the bot is supposed to say hi when someone says hi

```
from discord import client

client = discord.Client()
class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'Logged on as {self.user}!')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('hi'):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('hi')

client = MyClient()
client.run('MYTOKEN')
```

Comment: you should be more spesific if you want to someone to answer you.I mean, type error messages if you have, add discord-bot to tags etc

Comment: there arent any error messages

Comment: So you mean that when you type hi into the chat, the bot doesn't respond?

Comment: Did you make sure the bot has the correct permissions and is added to the server?

Comment: Also, you might need to add a `if message.author == client.user:` `return` because otherwise, it goes into an infinite loop: the bot says hi to you, then says hi to itself because someone(the bot) said a message starting with hi, and then says hi to the new message again, forever and ever. Your problem might be that discord recognizes spam and stops it.

Comment: yes to all of those, i was planning on adding the if statement later but i have all perms

Comment: The missing if statement might be the cause of the problem... Discord might block the bot if it tries to spam thousands of "hi"s into the chat.

Comment: @kenntnisse This is not the case. Discord would rate limit the bot, not prevent it altogether. @jxqk `on_message` is defined under the first `client`, yet you are running your second definition of `client`.

Comment: You're missing the intents. follow [this link](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment section, the code should be like this

```
@client.event()
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    elif message.content.startswith("hi")
        await message.channel.send("hi")
    ## another stuff put here
```

Comment: didnt work, no error message just didnt send anything

Comment: Which version did you use? 2.0 or stable one?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it looks like my original suspicion was wrong. TheFungusAmongUs's comment makes more sense, you just have to run the original client, not `MyClient`.

```
from discord import client

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged on as {client.user}!')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('hi'):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('hi')

#before, you were changing client to MyClient and then running it
client.run('MYTOKEN')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `@client.event on_message()` you need this little tidbit at the bottom of the dataclass for the other commands to run. Also, your `client = discord.Client()` needs more. Here is a good example of what it should look like:

```py
client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", intents = discord.Intents.default(), help_command=None)
```

should look like this :

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')
        #below command is needed because on_message overrides all commands and stops them from running see 4.4.22 readme for info
    await client.process_commands(message)
```